# Is it possible for googletags to track clicks from a referrer website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to distribute an ad to some my friend's websites, but how do i go about tracking the clicks from their site, going to my site?

I was looking at google-tags and google-analytics and i can't see any resources how or where i can start with that. I imagine that i should create a javascript snipper for the add, but is it still possible to track it?

Im expecting that when the user from a friend's site click my add, i would see in analytics the event and where the click came from. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Normally without doing anything, this traffic would be tracked as a "referral" from your friends' site.

You can find it under "Acquisition > All Traffic > Referrals"

Alternatively, you can use [UTM parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en) and have unique parameters for each of your friends.

Example link that you would give to your friend: https://www.mywebsite.com/?utm_campaign=myfriendsgroup&utm_source=friend1&utm_medium=banner

When someone visits your site by clicking on that link, they will show up under Acquisition > Campaigns > All Campaigns. In this case you will see the "myfriend" campaign.

You can then [segment these users](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en) and look at their activity.